# Angular 2/4/5 - Dynamic component gets recreated on each change detection

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a dynamic component using Angular's manual:

https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

I've successfully created the component but I noticed that I cannot use Material's tooltip.

After investigating it, I realized that the dynamic component gets recreated on each change detection (like when the mouse moves).

The way I understood it is by simply adding a console.log inside the OnInit function in my dynamic component.

And because of it, the tooltip doesn't work because it relies on the component's position before adding the tooltip.

Is that is the expected behavior?

This is the code of the component that loads the dynamic one.

```
export class UiTableCellComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentChecked {


@Input() dataRow: any;
@Input() columnDef: UitableColumn;
@ViewChild(UitablecompHostDirective) mgmtUitablecompHost: UitablecompHostDirective;

constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
}

ngOnInit() {
}

ngAfterContentChecked(): void {
  if (this.columnDef.cellDataComponent) {
    this.loadComponent();
  }
}

loadComponent() {

  const componentFactory = 

 this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.columnDef.cellDataComponent);

const viewContainerRef = this.mgmtUitablecompHost.viewContainerRef;
viewContainerRef.clear();

  const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
(<UitableComponent>componentRef.instance).data = this.dataRow;
}
```

}

Comment: Please read up on `ngAfterContentChecked` life cycle method, you will understand why

Comment: If I use the AfterViewInit I get this behavior also with addition of “changed after checked” error

Comment: Call it inside a `setTimeout` of `100` ms or so so it gets called in subsequent even loop tick to avoid changed after checked error